# How to prove $p(x)\geq m^2/4$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of $m$ subsets of a finite set $X$. For $x\in X$, let $p(x)$ be the number of pairs $(A,B)$ of sets $A,B\in \mathcal{F}$ such that either $x\in A\cap B$ or $x\not \in A\cup B$. Prove that $p(x)\geq m^2 /2$.

In the book I'm studying, writer has written the following hint:

Hint: Let $d(x)$ be the degree of $x$ in $\mathcal{F}$, and observe that $p(x)=d(x)^2+(m-d(x))^2$.

I was wondering if someone could help me about my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So have you shown the hint? What can you infer from the hint?

Comment: @Phicar On the one hand, the number of pairs $(A,B)$ of sets $A,B\in \mathcal{F}$ such that either $x\in A\cap B$ or $x\not \in A\cup B$ is $p(x)$ by definition. On the other hand, since $x\in A \cap B$, so $x$ is counted two times in terms of $d(x)$, hence $d(x)^2$, plus, since $x\not \in A\cup B$ which means $x\in A^c \cap B^c$, hence $(m-d(x))^2$. Then by the double counting principle, we have $p(x)=d(x)^2 +(m-d(x))^2$.

Comment: @Phicar If I can show that $d(x)\geq \frac{m}{2}$, the the result is obtained.

Comment: Nice, so the problem is in using the hint. Notice that you do not have $d(x)\geq m/2$ you can even see that if $d(x)=0$ then $p(x)=m^2.$ I suggest you add the comment showing the hint to the question. But what if you have that either $d(x)\geq m/2$ or $m-d(x)\geq m/2$?

Comment: @Phicar That's right. Then the proof is finished. I am so grateful for your help.

Comment: @Phicar Sorry, I made a mistake in the question. We must show that $p(x)\geq m^2 /2$.

Comment: Ok, I have answer this question. Please be sure to edit the title of your question then.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Well $m^2 = p(x)+(m^2-p(x))$ so either $p(x)\geq m^2/2$ or $m^2-p(x)> m^2/2$. Notice that the hint implies(or the way you solve it by counting) that $m^2-p(x)=2d(x)(m-d(x))$ **why?** 
We want to show that it is not possible that $2d(x)(m-d(x))> m^2/2$ can you factor the whole expression in a nice way?